# ZF2 injecting ACL into navigation

Tags: navigation, zend-framework2, acl

I have a working ACL module and Navigation setup in a Zend Framework 2 project.
The navigation object is generated and rendered properly, but it contains an element `admin` that I only want to be rendered when the logged in user has the role admin. The acl is properly blocking access (i.e. redirects to 403 page) when a non-admin tries to access any pages there, however the navigation still renders the nav-item.
The navigation setup is very simple (as it should be based on the read tutorials)

**module.config.php**

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
    ),
),
```

**view.phtml**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')
                    ->menu()
                    ->setMinDepth(0)
                    ->setMaxDepth(0)
                    ->setAcl($this->acl)
                    ->setRole('guest'); ?>
</div>
```

After a lot of debugging, I pinpointed where something is going wrong but I have no clue why or how to fix it. I tried var_dumping `$this->acl` in the view and it is set, as expected. However:

```
var_dump($this->navigation('navigation')->getAcl());
```

after the line with `setAcl()`, returns `NULL`. So somehow it seems that `setAcl($this->acl)` is not actually injecting the acl.

Comment: it's better to inject the ALC when you create the Navigation object. Create your own NavigationFactory and inject the ALC there. You can base it on the DefaultNavigationFactory just fine

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Andrew, unfortunately it didn't work out. I injected acl and role in custom factory. They now get set properly, I verified this. I went into the Zend files and in `Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/AbstractHelper.php` the function `accept` is checking the acl for page and role. Acl and role are set properly but still `accept` is returning `true` for all resources for every role. `accept` calls the function `isAllowed()` which calls `$this->getEventManager()->trigger(__FUNCTION__, $this, $params)` but I have no idea what this does

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by adding the property "resource" to each element of my navigation. Such property must match the name of a resource defined in your ACL.

Comment: Have you tried using the setDefault methods on navigation, @Pankrates? http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/integrating-bjyauthorize-with-zendnavigation/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding setAcl and setRole before menu:

```
echo $this->navigation('navigation')->setAcl($this->acl)->setRole($this->role)->menu()->setPartial('partial/navbar.phtml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in module bootstrap

```
\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation::setDefaultAcl($acl);
\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation::setDefaultRole($role);
```

Comment: Works fine in Module::onBootstrap() function in ZF3